# Checking most used colors in image

Tags: python, colors, python-imaging-library, counting, detect

I want to know the list of most used colors in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk7LO.jpg):

I tried the following code, but it takes too long:

```
from PIL import Image

colors = []
class Color:
    def __init__(self, m, c):
        self.col = c
        self.many = m

im = Image.open("~/.../strowberry.jpeg")
def cool():
    for i in im.getdata():
        i = str(i)
        i = i.replace(", ", "")
        i = i.replace("(", "")
        i = i.replace(")", "")
        i = int(i)
        colors.append(Color(1, i))
    for x in colors:
        num = 0
        for j in range(len(colors)):
            if x.col == colors[num].col:
                del colors[num]
                num -= 1
                x.many += 1
            num += 1
    for obj in colors:
        print(obj.many, obj.col)
cool()
```

Why is the code so slow and how can I improve the performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not reinvent the wheel. The Python Standard Library contains a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) that can do this for you much more efficiently. Using this, you don't need to iterate over the data yourself. You also do not need to define a Class and perform the string operations. The code is very short and simple:

```py
import collections
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('strawberry.jpg')
counter = collections.Counter(im.getdata())
for color in counter:
    print(f'{counter[color]} times color {color}')
```

If you really need the `Color` objects (for whatever you want to do with it later in your program), you can easily create this from the counter object using this one-liner:

```py
colors = [Color(counter[color], color) for color in counter]
```

...and if you really need it in the same string format as in your original code, use this instead:

```py
colors = [Color(counter[color], int(''.join(map(str, color)))) for color in counter]
```

Note that the two one-liners make use of *list comprehension*, which is very Pythonic and in many cases very fast as well.
The code `int(''.join(map(str, color)))` does the same as your 5 lines of code in the inner loop. This uses the fact that the original data is a tuple of integers, which can be converted to strings using `map(str, ...)` and then concatenated together using `''.join(...)`.

All this together took about 0.5 second on my machine, without the printing (which is slow anyway).